# Substring detection for 1st word

Tags: r, regex, string, substring, stringr

I am detecting substrings within reports and then adding suffix words to the end of the reports depending if the substring is present or absent. Shorter words are dangerous as they are usually parts of longer words. Example: **ear** and overb**ear**ing. The spacebar tends to be a reasonable solution. Therefore, instead of search for the substring 'ear' I will use ' ear'. Note the white space in front of the substring. And no white space at the end of the substring, as I don't want to miss the plural **ears**.
The problem is when the 1st word in the entire report is Ear. There is no leading white space.

I tried to solve the problem with library stringr but adding a space to the beginning of each report, but the text is returned unchanged.

```
(stringr)
Data$Fail <- str_pad(Data$text, width = 1, side = "left")
```

Comment: Why not just handle the 1st word issue conditionally?

Comment: using something like `^(ear)` looks for the group `ear` at the start of a line thanks to `^`.

Comment: use Regular expression library , it will help you find text by whatever pattern you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armali already answered your question (use `paste('',text)`) to add a space in front of ear. Since you also want to match the Ear at the start of a sentence you can better use a regex as pointed out by  HO LI Pin.

```
pattern <- '(?<![A-z])[Ee]ar'
```

This will only match E/ear if **not** preceded by any other letter (it can thus still be preceded by things like `_` ,`(`,  etc. but it is not clear from your question whether this is allowed or not.  Then you can either use the base R or simpler the `stringr` library to search all matches using this regex pattern:

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- '(?<![A-z])[Ee]ar'
text = 'Ear this is some nice text as you can hear with your ear about overbearing'

unlist(str_extract_all(text, pattern, simplify = FALSE))
```

Which will give you:

```
[1] "Ear" "ear"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data$Fail <- str_pad(Data$text, width = 1, side = "left")` didn't work because *`str_pad()` pads a string to a fixed length*, which you specified as `width = 1`, so it would only have inserted a space if the text were initially empty.

But if you just want to insert a space at the start of a string, you don't need a special library - `text = paste("", text)` would do.